# Set distances algorithm question

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have multiple sets containing integers. An integer maybe present in one set or multiple sets. I would like to find/match the sets with the most common integers.

Example
s1 {1, 2, 3, 4}
s2 {1, 3, 4, 5}
s3 {6, 7, 8, 9}
s4 {1, 6, 8, 10}

In this case, I would like to "efficiently" group s1+s2 as they have the most overlapping elements (3) followed by s3+s4(2) s1+s4(1).

You can do this the brute force way (match all possibilities - then sort)
Looking for an efficient way to do this.

Comment: The same set can appear more then once? Then I'm pretty sure the best you can do is O(n^2). If you'd consider only the best pair for each element, then the problem might be O(nlog(n)). Better then this is impossible because otherwise we could find out whether there are two equal elements in less than O(nlog(n)) which is known to be impossible.

Comment: can the same element appear more than once?  i.e., is {1,1,2,2,4} valid?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar a few years ago.  In my case we had tens of thousands of sets, and each set had around a dozen integers.  Not all sets had the same number of integers. Since these are "sets", I'm assuming the order of the integers in each set is irrelevant.

In our case, step 1 was to compute a hash of the numbers of each set.  We'd then sort the list of hashes and pull out the duplicates.

Step 2 was to compute the hash of each set less one element, then do the same.  For example,

s1 { 1,2,3,4 } would yield 4 hashes (2,3,4) and (1,3,4) and (1,2,4) and (1,2,3).

We'd make a new list associating all 4 hashes with s1 and sort/look for duplicates.  This would find the (1,3,4) match between s1 and s2.

We'd do a similar step 3 (omitting 2 from each set) and so on.  It took some experimentation to figure out where the cost/benefit cutoff was.  This is definitely an expensive brute force approach, but it worked well for us.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that all of your sets are of the same size (i.e. the same number of elements)

For ordered sets you sort on the first element O(nlog(n)), then start partitioning into equivalence classes.

1. Sort on the first element O(nlog(n))
2. Group the sets into classes by equivalence of the first element O(k)
3. In each class repeat the above two steps on the second element, the third element, etc.

For a given set size, this will be O(nlog(n)) overall, for n the number of sets.  It is not O(mlog(m)) for m, the number of set elements (size of the sets).

This is similar to a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) on a special metric.

I just noticed that you assume unordered sets, this answer from [theoretical CS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/is-there-a-hash-function-for-a-collection-i-e-multi-set-of-integers-that-has) has a good hash based solution, there can still be hash collisions, but you can reduce them as much as you want, to within the machine precision of the computer...